# How Can I Update Nested Array Element By Id

Tags: node.js, arrays, database, mongodb, mongoose

I'm new to mongodb , I want to update nested array element by id with findOneAndUpdate

```js
const Data = {
   items : [
      {
       id: 1,
       name : "a",
       child : [
         { id : 11, name "aa"},
         { id : 12, name "bb"},
        ]
      },
      {
       id: 2,
       name : "b",
       child : [
         { id : 22, name "ba"},
         { id : 23, name "bb"},
        ]
      },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Welcome!  Per stackoverflow policy, could you tell us what your target output looks like (an example of the update in action) and what specifically you have tried with `findOneAndUpdate` that does not work?

Comment: Note Update Nested Array Object By Id: 

const output = {
   items : [
      {
       id: 1,
       name : "a",
       child : [
         { id : 11, name "aa"},
         { id : 12, name "bb"},
        ]
      },
      {
       id: 2,
       name : "b",
       child : [
         { id : 22, name "ba"},
         { id : 23, name "cc"},
        ]
      },
    ]
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can do via arrayFilters:

```
 db.collection.update({},
  {
    $set: {
    "items.$[y].child.$[x].name": "cc"
    }
  },
  {
    arrayFilters: [
     {
      "x.id": 11
     },
     {
      "y.id": 1
     }
   ]
 })
```

Explained:
You specify which element you need to update via arrayFilter x and y , in the example this array element with id:11 in x and id:1 in y.
In the update operation you provide the new value for field name  , in the example this is value "cc"

[playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tDmBJsjT0s7)

Comment: I'm very thankful to you @R2D2, Thank You So Much,